# Creating a hash in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, controller, iteration

I have the makings of a method which calculates royalties for ISBNs. It splits sales by sales channel. The royalty rate is determined by the total quantity sold, and the royalty is calculated by multiplying the royalty rate (a percentage) by the total revenue. So the result should be a calculated royalty figure for each sales channel, for each isbn. Forgive what is probably over-commented code.

In the show method of the isbns_controller:

```
@isbn = Isbn.find(params[:id])

def royalty(isbn)
  @royaltiesbychannel = Hash.new()     
  # Returns all sales for the current isbn, and groups them by channel_id in a hash 
  # {1 => sale 1, sale 2}, {2 => sale 1, sale 2}
  # Then loops through each key-value pair.    
  @isbn.sales.group_by(&:channel_id).each do |ch_id, sale_array|
    # Takes the sales grouped by channel, and totals the quantities and values into two separate variables. 
    value_total_by_channel = sale_array.sum(&:value)  
    quantity_total_by_channel = sale_array.sum(&:quantity)  
     # Gets all the rules for the isbn
     @isbn.rules.each do |rule|
       # Jumps to the next sales hash unless the channel ids match
       next unless rule.channel_id == ch_id
       if Range.new(rule.lower,rule.upper).include?(quantity_total_by_channel)
         @royaltiesbychannel[ch_id] = value_total_by_channel * rule.rate
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

It's that last line which is giving me a problem. What I want is to produce a hash with the channel ids as the keys, and the calculated royalties as the values. But instead, it's producing a hash with just one key-value pair, in something which looks like this:

```
{1=>#<BigDecimal:10132a620,'0.875E5',9(36)>}
```

I suspect there's something wrong with the way I'm creating a new hash at the top of the method, and also with trying to declare the key in the square brackets.

The `rule.rate` is a percentage expressed as a decimal, e.g. 0.10. The value is an integer (at the moment, at least). Any thoughts on how to generate this hash?

Secondly, what's the best way to iterate through the resultant hash in the view?

Many thanks in advance.

Update - output of .inspect as requested:

```
{1=>[#<Sale id: 1, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 3000, value: 122000, currency: "", total_quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-05-16 19:52:36", updated_at: "2011-05-22 14:28:33", customer: "WHS", retail_price: nil, discount: nil, channel_id: 1, invoice_date: "2011-02-01", rule_id: nil>, #<Sale id: 2, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 500, value: 3000, currency: "", total_quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-05-19 09:55:00", updated_at: "2011-05-19 09:55:00", customer: "Borders", retail_price: nil, discount: nil, channel_id: 1, invoice_date: nil, rule_id: nil>], 2=>[#<Sale id: 6, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 10, value: 2000, currency: "", total_quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-05-19 10:34:34", updated_at: "2011-05-19 11:21:07", customer: "Bookshop a", retail_price: nil, discount: nil, channel_id: 2, invoice_date: nil, rule_id: nil>, #<Sale id: 7, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 2000, value: 4000, currency: "", total_quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-05-19 10:34:49", updated_at: "2011-05-19 10:34:49", customer: "Bookshop b", retail_price: nil, discount: nil, channel_id: 2, invoice_date: nil, rule_id: nil>]}
```

Second update: revision to the question:

Thanks for your thoughts so far. It turns out the method is working fine, because the hash generated by `@isbn.sales.group_by(&:channel_id)` only contains one key-value pair. So my question still stands, but for a different bit of my code: how do I perform a find on the Sales model to produce an array of hashes like  `{1 => sale 1, sale 2}, {2 => sale 1, sale 2}`?

I have tried this horrible thing:

```
@channelarray = Channel.select(:id).all  
@salesbychannelwrong = @channelarray.group_by {|i| Sale.where("channel_id = ?",i).where("isbn_id =?", @isbn)}   
@salesbychannel = @salesbychannelwrong.invert
```

which gives this:

```
{[#<Channel id: 1>]=>[#<Sale id: 1, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 3000, value: 122000, currency: "", total_quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-05-16 19:52:36", updated_at: "2011-05-22 14:28:33", customer: "WHS", retail_price: nil, discount: nil, channel_id: 1, invoice_date: "2011-02-01", rule_id: nil>, #<Sale id: 2, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 500, value: 3000, currency: "", total_quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-05-19 09:55:00", updated_at: "2011-05-19 09:55:00", customer: "Borders", retail_price: nil, discount: nil, channel_id: 1, invoice_date: nil, rule_id: nil>], [#<Channel id: 2>]=>[#<Sale id: 6, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 10, value: 2000, currency: "", total_quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-05-19 10:34:34", updated_at: "2011-05-19 11:21:07", customer: "Bookshop a", retail_price: nil, discount: nil, channel_id: 2, invoice_date: nil, rule_id: nil>, #<Sale id: 7, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 2000, value: 4000, currency: "", total_quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-05-19 10:34:49", updated_at: "2011-05-19 10:34:49", customer: "Bookshop b", retail_price: nil, discount: nil, channel_id: 2, invoice_date: nil, rule_id: nil>]}
```

I have also tried

```
Sale.find_by_isbn_id(:id).group_by(&:channel_id)
```

which returns `nil`

and this

```
Sale.find_by_isbn_id(@isbn).group_by(&:channel_id)
```

which returns

```
undefined method `group_by' for #<Sale:0x0000010122df60>
```

I have the following models:

```
class Sale
  belongs_to :isbn
  belongs_to :channel
  ...
end

class Isbn
  has_many :rules
  has_many :sales
  has_many :channels, :through => :sales
  ...
end

class Channel
  has_many :sales
  has_many :rules
  ...
end

class Rule
  belongs_to :isbn
  belongs_to :channel
  has_many :sales, :through => :isbn
  ...
end
```

Thanks again.

Comment: What does @isbn.sales.group_by(&:channel_id).size return?

Comment: Hello Andy - it returns 2 when I put it in an instance variable and into the views > isbns > show.html.erb file. Thanks for taking the time...

Comment: Can you output @isbn.sales.group_by(&:channel_id).inspect in the view and paste it here?

Comment: Thanks, @dmarkow, for sorting out the formatting.

Comment: due to your output, your hash is fine. there is only one item in entry Hash, so there is only one item in final hash

Comment: Well there's a thing. Thank you! Erm, any ideas how I can produce the hash I want, up at the top there, which does something more like `{1 => sale 1, sale 2}, {2 => sale 1, sale 2}` ?

Comment: Your approach seems ok but I suspect that @isbn.sales isn't returning what you think it is.

Comment: @Andy Waite is right. And it looks like you're totally missed in your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sale.find_by_isbn_id(@isbn).group_by(&:channel_id)` => `Sale.find_all_by_isbn_id(@isbn).group_by(&:channel_id)`

or

```
Sale.where(:ibn_id => @isbn.id).group_by(&:channel_id)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but each of those still produces this: 

`{1=>[#<Sale id: 1, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 3000, rule_id: nil>], 2=>[#<Sale id: 6, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 10, value: 2000, rule_id: nil>]}`

rather than the desired:

`{1=>[#<Sale id: 1, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 3000, rule_id: nil>]}, {2=>[#<Sale id: 6, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 10, value: 2000, rule_id: nil>]}`

Comment: You will never get this in Ruby `{1=>[#<Sale id: 1, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 3000, rule_id: nil>]}, {2=>[#<Sale id: 6, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 10, value: 2000, rule_id: nil>]}`. You can return an Array of Hashes like: `[{1=>[#<Sale id: 1, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 3000, rule_id: nil>]}, {2=>[#<Sale id: 6, isbn_id: 2, quantity: 10, value: 2000, rule_id: nil>]}]`.

Comment: Thanks, @fl00r. Could you help me to return an array of hashes as you correctly point out?

Comment: I'll come back when I've re-read this big pile of books, here. Thanks again for your help!